# ui-route have three states setting a route and how is it done?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, state

so basically, I'm trying set up a app function where you click on a user profile and you go to that profile then on that profile there a link that goes to the user photo gallery. how would I set this up in ui router?

```
    .state('match', {
        url: '/match',
        controller: 'matchCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'partials/match.html'
    })
    .state('match.list', {
        url: '/list',
        controller: 'matchCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'partials/match.list.html'
    })
    .state('match.profile', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'partials/match.profile.html',
        resolve: {
            profile: function ($stateParams, Account) {
                return Account.getUserProfile($stateParams.id)
                    .then(function (profile) {
                        return profile;
                    });
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, profile) {
            $scope.user = profile;
        }
    })
    .state('match.profile.gallery', {
        url: '/gallery',
        templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
        controller: 'galleryCtrl'
    })
```

how would the match.profile.gallery be set up in order to work?

Comment: But what exactly is the problem?

Comment: it not working, and not sure why?